# Get the first record of model in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need a way to get first record of specific model .at this time im using a way like this :

```
this.store.findAll('configModel').then(function(items) {
 items.get('content')[0].set('isEnableShowUniqueName', true);
 items.get('content')[0].set('isSavedToServer', false);
 items.get('content')[0].save();
});
```

but I think there is a better and ember way out there? is this way true? do you know any better way? but know this I haven't id of record I need the only first record of the model.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have firstObject, lastObject and objectAt.

```
items.get('firstObject');
```

Comment: Here is a github issue using it: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/551#issuecomment-31436785

Comment: there has to be a better way to write this when Ember moves to typescript